# Accessing model data, from MVC3 partial view, in controller without passing it explicitly in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, controller, httprequest

I have a MVC3 partial view that is called with a model.

```
@model SomeModel
```

The model have an Id parameter.

In the view I call `@Html.Action("SomeMethod", "SomeController")`

Is there any way to access the Id parameter in the SomeMethod ActionResult without passing it explicitly like this:

```
@Html.Action("SomeMethod", "SomeController", new {"Id" = Model.Id})
```

The problem is that I can not change the source code of the partial view. And I need the Id value. The Id is not used in the partial view so I can not access it via JavaScript.
Is the model passed to the HttpContext and is there any way to pass it?

**EDIT:** The thing is that I am developing a plugin for [nopCommerce](http://nopcommerce.com/), like the ones that are offered by [nop-templates](http://www.nop-templates.com/). [nopCommerce](http://nopcommerce.com/) is an open source software and I can change the code, but the plugin will be shipped separately, so it is not recommended to make changes in [nopCommerce](http://nopcommerce.com/) views and the view that I am referring to is such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you can't change the sourcecode of the partial view, there is no way of getting to the id value in your controller. Its completely decoupled as thats one major point of the MVC pattern.
You have to explicitely pass it as a parameter to your action.
A dirty workaround might be to store that id somewhere in the `Session`.

Answer (score 1):

In my project i fill my state drop down list by country id  like this

in my view

i pass country id to my controller ActionResult  like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cascadingdropdown() {          
        var countryID = $('#countryID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Content("~/City/State")",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { countryId: countryID },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#stateID").empty();
                $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                    alert(optiondata.StateName);
                    $("#stateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ID + "'>" + optiondata.StateName + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Faild To Retrieve states.');
            }

        });
    } 
</script>
```

in my controller i have action

```
public JsonResult State(int countryId)
{                
 var stateList = CityRepository.GetList(countryId);
 return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

i think this will help you ....

Comment: As I sad in my post the Id is not used anywhere in the partial view and I can not change the source code, so your method will not help me. If this was not the case, this method is very useful. The Id can also be added as an attribute to html element and accessed unobtrusively.